# map function in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to implement map function in VB.NET and I have tried the below.

```
 Function Map(a,f)
    Dim i
    for each i in a
      f(i)
    next
 End Function

 Function alert(a)
    MessageBox.Show(a)
 end function
```

But the above code is not working and saying alert is not declared.
Please help me on this.

Comment: No datatypes? Are you sure this is VB.NET code and not VB6 or VBS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your functions don't return anything. Try this:

```
Public Sub Map(Of T)(ByVal a As IEnumerable(Of T), ByVal f As Action(T))
    For Each i As T In a
      f(i)
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub alert(ByVal a As Object)
    MessageBox.Show(a)
End Sub
```

Above is based on the methods from the question. An actual traditional `Map()` function might look more like this:

```
Public Iterator Function Map(Of T)(ByVal a As IEnumerable(Of T), ByVal f As Func(Of T,T)) As IEnumerable(Of T)
    For Each i As T In a
        Yield f(i)
    Next
End Function
```

Or this:

```
Public Iterator Function Map(Of T, U)(ByVal a As IEnumerable(Of T), ByVal f As Func(Of T, U)) As IEnumerable(Of U)
    For Each i As T In a
        Yield f(i)
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: This isn't `map`. It's `each` as it doesn't return a result.

Comment: @Cuadue Old now, but you're right! Today I'd do it different, and am finally updating the answer to show a more correct version.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a vb expert. But if you are using vb.net. It should be like this:

```
MessageBox.Show("Your Message Here")
```

I in vb6 it is like this:

```
MsgBox("Your Message Here")
```

The reason why i am asking is that. In vb.net you can use

```
Option Strict OFF
```

and then you don't have to declare any types. But by default in vb.net it set to

```
Option Strict ON
```